# How to add message box for buttons in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add the message box (JavaScript) when click button in client Application.

when Click "YES" will trigger the controller and Click "NO" will stay the view.

```
        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="location.href ='@Url.Action("PreviewBills","Sites",new {id = Model.Id},null)'">
                Preview Invoices
            </button>
       </div>
```

and I tried to apply the following code, but msgbox doesn't response.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Site";
}
<div style="float:left;width:24%;height:100%;">


    <fieldset>


            <button type="button" onclick="preview()">
                Preview Invoices
            </button>

    </fieldset>

</div>



<script>
    function preview() {
        var r = confirm("Please confirm.");
        if (r == true) {

            location.href ='@Url.Action("PreviewBills","Sites",new {id = Model.Id},null)';
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any guide or induction will be appreciated

Comment: _"When I used "System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo" in my controller, it works fine. But when i deployed to the server, it's not working."_ - huh? Why are you trying to use UI code to execute on the server machine?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Realized that.I shouldn't. Just need help to add message box popup before process.

Comment: You will need some JavaScript ‘confirm‘ call there

Comment: You shouldn't attempt to pop up anything on the server, not least because the server process likely runs under a different user account. If you mean you want a message in the browser, you need to do that in client code (javascript).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will rephrase my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function confirmRequest() {
  var r = confirm("Please confirm.");
  if (r == true) {
    location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
    //location.href ='@Url.Action("PreviewBills","Sites",new {id = Model.Id},null)';
  } else {
    //do nothing
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="confirmRequest();">
                Preview Invoices
            </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the code- what you did and what browser you are using ?

Comment: The code is correct as you can see it runs in above snippet as well. Did you try to run above snippet , did it run ? What web browser you are using ?

Comment: Thanks Sak, it works. I had two <script></script> in the html. As soon as I merge to one, works.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- It's free. From https://AdsReg.com/ Don't remove this line. This is our advertisement. Thanks. -->
<link href='https://adsreg.com/Try-It-Yourself/samples/How-To-Web/2023/008-MessageBox9306/AdsRegAlertBox9306.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src="https://adsreg.com/Try-It-Yourself/samples/How-To-Web/2023/008-MessageBox9306/AdsRegAlertBox9306.js"></script>

<div id="AdsRegMessageBox9306"></div>
<div class="AdsRegSweet-alert2" style="top:2%; bottom:2%; position:fixed;margin-top:0px; display:block;z-index:0;overflow-y:auto;">
<h1>Command Control Buttons</h1>
<br />

<hr />
<span>With Your Own Code For Access Multiple Messages Control</span><br />
<button onclick="AdsRegMessageShow9306('AdsRegMessageBox9306','success','www.AdsReg.com - Title','Set background to red? Our Side click = Blue','Okay Sure','yes','yellow is better','','sky01');">Success</button>
<button onclick="AdsRegMessageShow9306('AdsRegMessageBox9306','error','www.AdsReg.ca - Title','Your Error Message Text<br>pink? Our side is white!','Try Pink COLOR.','yes','I want green','','sky02');">Error</button>
<button onclick="AdsRegMessageShow9306('AdsRegMessageBox9306','info','Hossein Lotfali - Title','Is Gray good?<br>Out side is red!','Yes Gray is good','yes','No white is better','','sky03');">Info</button>
<button onclick="AdsRegMessageShow9306('AdsRegMessageBox9306','warning','Canada.AdsReg.com Title','Hello set blue?<br>Our side is pink!','Yes!','yes','I want Silver','','sky04');">Warning</button>
<br />

<button onclick="AdsRegMessageShow9306('AdsRegMessageBox9306','custom','www.AdsReg.com - Title','Set background to red? Our Side click = Blue','Okay Sure','yes','yellow is better','https://adsreg.com/Try-It-Yourself/samples/How-To-Web/2023/008-MessageBox9306/images/AdsReg01.png','sky01');">Custom01</button>
<button onclick="AdsRegMessageShow9306('AdsRegMessageBox9306','custom','www.AdsReg.ca - Title','Your Error Message Text<br>pink? Our side is white!','Try Pink COLOR.','yes','I want green','https://adsreg.com/Try-It-Yourself/samples/How-To-Web/2023/008-MessageBox9306/images/AdsReg02.png','sky02');">Custom02</button>
<button onclick="AdsRegMessageShow9306('AdsRegMessageBox9306','custom','Hossein Lotfali - Title','Is Gray good?<br>Out side is red!','Yes Gray is good','yes','No white is better','https://adsreg.com/Try-It-Yourself/samples/How-To-Web/2023/008-MessageBox9306/images/AdsReg03.png','sky03');">Custom03</button>
<button onclick="AdsRegMessageShow9306('AdsRegMessageBox9306','custom','Canada.AdsReg.com Title','Hello set blue?<br>Our side is pink!','Yes!','yes','I want Silver','https://adsreg.com/Try-It-Yourself/samples/How-To-Web/2023/008-MessageBox9306/images/AdsReg04.jpg','sky04');">Custom04</button>

<br />
<button onclick="AdsRegMessageShow9306('AdsRegMessageBox9306','success','www.AdsReg.com - Title','Set background to red? Our Side click = Blue','Okay Sure','yes','','','sky01');">Success Single Button</button>
<button onclick="AdsRegMessageShow9306('AdsRegMessageBox9306','warning','www.AdsReg.com - Title','Set background to red? Our Side click = Blue','Okay Sure','no','','','sky01');">Warning Single Button No Back</button>

<p>
We have triple actions<br />
1: First button click<br>
2: Second button click<br>
3: Black back area click (Out of message box)<br>
Start your experience  by clicking on buttons and answer dialog boxes
</p>
<div style="text-align:center;"><hr />
<a href="https://canada.adsreg.com/" target="_blank">
<img src="https://canada.adsreg.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/MainFile01-copy.png" style="width:400px; max-width:90%; border-radius:12px;" alt="AdsReg Logo" /><br /><br />
</a><a href="https://adsreg.com/"><img src="https://adsreg.com/english/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2023/02/TopSiteLogo_AdsReg9-2048x429.webp" style="width:400px; max-width:90%; border-radius:7px;" alt="AdsReg Logo" />
</a><br /><br />
Copyright AdsReg.com - All Right Reserved.
<a href="https://adsreg.com/english/?p=1042" target="_blank"><h2>Return to article now</h2></a>
</div>
</div>



<script>
function RunYourScriptFunction9306A(ElementId,MsgOwnCode)
{
if (MsgOwnCode == "sky01"){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="red";}
else if (MsgOwnCode == "sky02"){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="pink";}
else if (MsgOwnCode == "sky03"){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="gray";}
else if (MsgOwnCode == "sky04"){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="blue";}
}
function RunYourScriptFunction9306B(ElementId,MsgOwnCode)
{
if (MsgOwnCode == "sky01"){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="yellow";}
else if (MsgOwnCode == "sky02"){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="green";}
else if (MsgOwnCode == "sky03"){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="white";}
else if (MsgOwnCode == "sky04"){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="silver";}
}
function RunYourScriptFunction9306C(ElementId,MsgOwnCode)
{
if (MsgOwnCode == "sky01"){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="blue";}
else if (MsgOwnCode == "sky02"){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="white";}
else if (MsgOwnCode == "sky03"){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="red";}
else if (MsgOwnCode == "sky04"){document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="pink";}
}
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.